# Connected components of metric space are closed

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

I'm working on the following exercise (from T.Tao's Analysis 2 book):

"Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and define a relation $x-y$ on $X$ by declaring $x-y$ iff there exists a connected subset of $X$ which contains both $x$ and $y$.
Show that: 
(1) this is in equivalence relation;
(2) the equivalence classes of this relation (i.e. the sets $\{y\in X:y-x\}$ for some $x\in X$) are connected;
(3) the equivalence classes of this relation (i.e. the sets $\{y\in X:y-x\}$ for some $x\in X$) are closed."

I've managed to show both (1) and (2) but I haven't been able to prove (3)
 (I've also searched for similar posts but this hasn't helped me either) so I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you show that if $A$ is connected, then $\bar{A}$, the closure of $A$ in $X$, must also be connected? Use this, and the definition of connected component to show that we must then have $A = \bar{A}$, hence $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the fact that, when a set is conneced, its closure is connected too. So, if $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$, then $\overline{[x]}=[x]$, because if $y\in[x]$, then there's a connected set which contains both $x$ and $y$ (namely, $\overline{[x]}$) and therefore $y\in[x]$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose an equivalence class isn't closed. Then there is an element outside it such that every open neighbourhood of that element meets the equivalence class. Then conclude that either there is an open neighbourhood of that element which does not meet your equivalence class or that your element outside your equivalence class is actually in your equivalence class